# How to update UI with WatchKit?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel, watchkit

I created a sample `watchkit` app and I dragged a UIButton and UILabel into the storyboard app scene. I was able to hook up the `UIButton` to the interface controller and got it to update the `UILabel`.

But the `label.text` was not reflected in the simulator. Nothing changes. Do I have to call something to update the UI?

I have made sure to connect both the `UILabel` and `UIButton` to variables in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update a `WKInterfaceLabel`'s text property you need to use `setText()`:

```
self.myLabel.setText("new text")
```